# SSL between Kafka and Spark

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

We are using Kafka,Spark Streaming and loading data to Cassandra

Need to implement a security layer between nodes running kafka and nodes running spark.

Any guidance on how to implement SSL between kafka and spark nodes ?

Thanks
Sreeni

Comment: Using KafkaUtils.createDirectStream which present in Kafka client 0.8 API.

Comment: Reference - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15089

Comment: cassandra evangelists , Any updates ?

Comment: I am hoping that Spark is running some consumer to fetch data before loading to Cassandra.. You can use the Kafka SSL/ACL  as per below links       http://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-security-authorization-authentication-encryption       and https://github.com/Symantec/kafka-security-0.9

Comment: thanks.. i know that kafka 0.9 supports SSL but spark does not support SSL with kafka. kafka 0.8 can work with spark but we need to ssl to get this integration to production

Comment: Hi Srini, did you figure out any workaround for this ? I am also using Spark 1.4.1 and Kafka 0.9.0.0 and I want to enable SSL, is it possible ?