# Enabling SSL between Apache spark and Kafka broker

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am trying to enable the SSL between my Apache Spark 1.4.1 and Kafka 0.9.0.0 and I am using `spark-streaming-kafka_2.10` Jar to connect to Kafka and I am using  `KafkaUtils.createDirectStream` method to read the data from Kafka topic.

Initially, I got OOM issue and I have resolved it by increasing the Driver memory, after that I am seeing below issue, I have done little bit of reading and found out that `spark-streaming-kafka_2.10` 
uses Kafka 0.8.2.1 API, which doesn't support SSL (Kafka supports SSL only after 0.9.0.0 versions). are there any alternatives to enable SSL between Spark 1.4.1 and Kafka 0.9.0.0.

- http://grokbase.com/p/kafka/users/158wy0wtxk/ssl-between-kafka-and-spark-streaming-api
- [SSL between Kafka and Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37743490/ssl-between-kafka-and-spark)
- http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-integration.html
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-15089

Here is the log

```
iableProperties: Property security.protocol is not valid
16/10/24 18:25:09 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.truststore.location is not valid
16/10/24 18:25:09 WARN utils.VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.truststore.password is not valid
16/10/24 18:25:09 INFO utils.VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to 
16/10/24 18:25:09 INFO consumer.SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to error

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: java.io.EOFException
org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFromReadableChannel(NetworkReceive.java:99)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for Kafka 0.10 (which has SSL support) has been added to Spark 2.0. we have to use maven artifact spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10.

Comment: my spark version = 2.4.5 kafka version = 2.2.1 I am running the below spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10:2.0.0 --master local sparkstreamingKafka.py and getting the error kafka.py", line 217, in _get_helper
TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable. Can you kindly help.

Comment: I am trying to connect to broker using SSL. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,