# Spark streaming with kafka(ssl enabled)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

I have seen multiple questions regarding this topic but unable to find an answer for it? I have tried to add comments and have not got any response yet.

Requirement -> spark-streaming with Kafka **SSL enabled**
Below are the version details

I am running spark locally.

Spark -> version 2.4.6

kafka version -> 2.2.1

code snippet:

```
import sys
import logging
from datetime import datetime

try:
    from pyspark import SparkContext
    from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
    from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
    sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingDirectKafkaWordCount")
    ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 20)
    brokers = "b1:p,b2:p"
    topic = "topic1"
    kafkaParams = {"security.protocol":"SSL","metadata.broker.list": brokers}
    kvs = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, [topic],kafkaParams)
    lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
    print(lines)
    counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" ")) \
                  .map(lambda word: (word, 1)) \
                  .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
    counts.pprint()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
except ImportError as e:
    print("Error importing Spark Modules :", e)
    sys.exit(1)
```

When I am submitting it as below.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.10:2.0.0 --master local pysparkKafka.py
```

This is due to the reference I took from this
[Enabling SSL between Apache spark and Kafka broker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40230237/enabling-ssl-between-apache-spark-and-kafka-broker)

I am getting the below error

```
Spark Streaming's Kafka libraries not found in class path. Try one of the following.

  1. Include the Kafka library and its dependencies with in the
     spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8:2.4.6 ...

  2. Download the JAR of the artifact from Maven Central http://search.maven.org/,
     Group Id = org.apache.spark, Artifact Id = spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly, Version = 2.4.6.
     Then, include the jar in the spark-submit command as

     $ bin/spark-submit --jars <spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly.jar> ...
```

Now when I submit it as below. This is due to seeing the above error and picking a jar from maven.

```
spark-submit --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.0.2 --master local pysparkKafka.py
```

I am getting the below error with the SSL port of the brokers.

```
20/07/24 11:58:46 INFO VerifiableProperties: Verifying properties
20/07/24 11:58:46 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property group.id is overridden to
20/07/24 11:58:46 WARN VerifiableProperties: Property security.protocol is not valid
20/07/24 11:58:46 INFO VerifiableProperties: Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to
20/07/24 11:58:46 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
20/07/24 11:58:47 INFO SimpleConsumer: Reconnect due to socket error: java.io.EOFException: Received -1 when reading from channel, socket has likely been closed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Note -> The above submit works well without SSL. But my requirement is to  enable SSL.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.